# Why would Vickers use the term half-a-billion miles?

Tags: dialogue, prometheus

Why would Vickers use the term "half-a-billion miles" in *Prometheus*?

As we know, that sort of distance from Earth is still well within the solar system -- about the distance to Jupiter. Obviously it was just an expression indicating a great distance but in a time where companies, perhaps even individuals, can spend a *trillion* dollars on a project (as was emphasized in the movie), the impact of a billion when trying to convey a large number is diminished.

If she had said half a *zillion* that would have worked much better. I am wondering why this was not changed if in the script or if it was a mistake made by the actor herself or some improvisation on her part.

Comment: I hate questions that start with the phrase "As we all know...". In-universe, it's entirely possible that Vickers didn't know that. Out-of-universe, it's entirely possible that neither the actress nor the scriptwriters knew that. [Sci-Fi Writers Have No Sense Of Scale](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ScifiWritersHaveNoSenseOfScale), after all.

Comment: I am sorry for subjecting you to a question that begins with "as we all know" but I did not want to present what I consider common knowledge as if I was a rarely sophisticated watcher of flicks who had caught something. I am interested in knowing if the writer wanted to convey something about Vickers since a technical adviser would have caught this error even if the writer had no knowledge of astronomical distances.

Comment: In fact *in*-universe it's already likely the character simply didn't care. It's a throwaway phrase barring *any* kind of physical accuracy. A billion still is a huge number. Why do people say "thank god" when they don't believe in god? A few years of space exploration won't change English idioms.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I think that the dollar cost of the  expedition being 1000 billion of which Vickers is very aware and the use of a billion describing some huge distance is inconsistent. Very few people would travel many billions (trillions in fact) of miles without know that they had. If it is a way of indicating her contempt for the expedition -- she couldn't be bothered even to know how far she had traveled -- then that is a good line. If it just remained in the movie and means nothing, that seems sloppy.

Comment: I don't know how much thought the screenwriters or Ms. Theron spent on it, but I'd guess it's at least more than Ms. *Vickers* spent on it.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: my default assumption is the writers think an awful lot about things like that so rather than assume the writer was sloppy or ignorant I try to think why the line could have been intentional and carefully considered. So I think my last word on this is that they were trying to show that Vickers did not care enough to even find out how far she had flown because she disliked the whole project. A very poor attitude which however was not responsible for her death and she ended up way better off the Shaw did -- Shaw probably wished the engineer had killed her many times.

Comment: @Relesabe I haven't seen the movie but if Vickers uses miles instead of kilometers she may be American or British.  If she is British she may use the long scale where a billion is 10 to the 12th power instead of 10 to the 9th power. Thus half a billion miles would be a thousand times farther, though still just a 12th of a light year.

Comment: @M.A.Golding: I had not thought of that. The writer is american, the character is american but the director is british and it is certainly possible that he never thought of it being an "intra-solar-system" distance and maybe the writer was writing for Ridley Scottt. As you say, still a modest distance. I recall old Outer Limits where the spoke of planets 1 million miles from Earth and that rankled even when I was a little kid. Again, it is possible they wanted to reveal something about Vickers.

Comment: If Ridley Scott used ‚zillion‘ in his script for hyperbole, i‘d be disappointed in his ability to make a world so lived in, regardless of the opinions of his films, they all look alive. This is nothing more that an idiom the writers didn‘t think about. There is no statement beyond ‚we‘re super duper far away‘

Answer (score 2):

### It's in the [script](https://www.avpgalaxy.net/files/scripts/script-paradise-lindelof.pdf)

As for "why it was not changed" or just adjusted in the script, this is merely *hyperbole* and not intended to be an accurate representation of the actual distance.

It's impossible to state *why* billion was used rather than any other extremely large number...it's just Vicker's way of speaking (at least as written).

Comment: Thanks, interesting that it is in the script and one wonders if this was a way of establishing how unsophisticated scientifically Vickers was. She definitely seemed very negative about the prospects of the mission, perhaps had argued against the huge expenditure with her father. So maybe they just wanted to show that she had no scientific curiosity or knowledge?

Comment: @Paulie_D  - Actually calling an interstellar distance, if that was the actual distance referrred to, "half a billion miles" would be hypobole and not hyperbole.  Even one light year's distance would be 5 trillion, 878 billion, etc. miles.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus is over 34 light years from earth which is over 200 trillion miles from earth that is over 200 million billion miles  so to say half billion miles. Its like saying a trip from New York to Los Angeles is five inches out the door. So you see if they were being facetious , the distance is so astronomical different so being facetious really don't look good in that writing of the story just my opinion. It would have been better to say a few light years from earth .

Comment: exactly, unless they wanted to show she was sort of a dabbler, there because of her dad. she said some other silly things also.